# Tag merging suggestion: [joystick] [joypad] [gamepad]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

I propose to merge [joystick](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/joystick) [joypad](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/joypad) and [gamepad](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/gamepad) (with a total of 25 questions) into  [game-controller](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/game-controller); as we do not get many questions targeting one specific type of game controller, instead, having one tag to refer to all game controllers.

Comment: This is a difficult one (for the joystick part of the merge). I don't *generally* think that somewhat related, little used tags should be merged, if they are actually useful. But [search for racing wheel](http://superuser.com/search?q=racing+wheel) finds a few matches we could include, and a few uses of [tag:controller] are also game controller related.

Comment: @DanielBeck questions under [tag:controller] that were about game controllers retagged to [tag:game-controller] (5 total)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completed as part of the [Super User mid 2012 tag/question cleanup](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5054/super-user-mid-2012-tag-question-cleanup?lq=1) .