# Super User mid 2012 tag/question cleanup

Tags: support, tags, clean-up

During my course of reviewing, editing & general janitorial cleanup, I ran into a few tags that were pretty much useless. Since there's too much for me to take action up, I'm posting the list here.

Some guidelines:

- **Don't just fix the tag; review the question and fix anything else you can find in the process.** If there are grammatical errors, then please fix them. If a question is pure crap and doesn't belong on Super User, make sure to cast a close/delete vote. If the question is old and won't get enough close/delete votes, then flag for moderator attention or drop the link in [Vote to Close/Delete chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117/super-user-vote-to-close-delete)
- Don't ping for others in main Root Access room - that's just noise. Make use of the existing rooms.
- If the tag is to be removed, then its tag wiki excerpt should be updated as follows:

  > DO NOT USE - Removed as part of Super User mid 2012 cleanup - `https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5054/super-user-mid-2012-tag-question-cleanup`

  And the following should be added to the top of the tag wiki body

  > DO NOT USE - Removed as part of [Super User mid 2012 tag/question cleanup](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5054/super-user-mid-2012-tag-question-cleanup)

---

Please update the question as and when progress is made.

### Important

Do not flag/vote to close for migration; many of them are too old, too highly upvoted, just plain crap, or out of scope according to their FAQ.

**Remember, we don't migrate crap.**

In this case, as mentioned above, cast your vote for closure and/or deletion and also flag for moderator attention and we'll review it.

#### Pro-tip #1

If you are removing tags from a massive amount of questions, it's better to go to the last question on the last page of all questions with that tag and work your way backwards. This prevents you from having to deal with the cache not reflecting your edits on the question list combined with browser-cache issues.

If you haven't visited most of these questions, you'll know what you changed because the link for the question will have a different color.

#### Pro-tip #2

Please edit in small batches & be mindful of front-page flooding - we don't want the entire front page to be filled with edits of old questions.

---

Tags in question:

- [communication](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/communication)
- [sharing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sharing)
- [disk](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/disk)
- [conversation](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/conversation)
- [flickering](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/flickering)
- [settings](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/settings)
- [middle-mouse-button](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/middle-mouse-button)

Disambiguation:

- [images](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/images) (945)

  Even the tag wiki is conflicted:

  > Questions tagged with this question can refer to graphical images, e.g. a .jpg or .gif file or system snapshots, which are also called "images".
- [history](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/history)

  > History often refers to the list of webpages viewed in a browser or commands used in a particular program. History is often used for undo/redo or back/forward functionality in programs of all kinds.

---

<sup>Question text borrowed liberally from similar post on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012), thanks guys!</sup>

Comment: If these tags just need to be removed and not disambiguated, why not ping a dev about it and be done with it?

Comment: In any case, that'd also be a good occasion to go through open burnination requests and see what's still missing from there.

Comment: Are we discussing the ones suggested as to be removed, or are we just assuming that these are to be removed?

Comment: these are to be removed + open to suggestions for more to be removed. @KronoS.

Comment: @slhck thought it'd be a good idea to clean up/close/delete questions regd these instead of blind burnination

Comment: What about this [clean up](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/tagged/clean-up) tag that nobody uses?

Comment: @KronoS /me grins

Comment: Every time I read this title, I half expect it to say a "mid summers night cleanup" :P

Comment: Congrats guys!  We finished up this list.

Comment: @KronoS: Not quite yet...

Comment: @OliverSalzburg it is now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>[prices](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/prices) should be removed as well. 6 of the 10 questions are closed; it is mainly used for shopping reccommendations.</strike> - Done!

**EDIT 1:**

<strike>[joystick](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/joystick) (14) & [joypad](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/joypad) (4) & [gamepad](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/gamepad) (13) should be retagged into [game-controller](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/game-controller); as we don't get many questions on the site about game controllers, I think we don't need to have tags for each seperately.</strike> - Done!

<strike>There is also [old](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/old), [retro](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/retro), [vintage](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/vintage), and [old-hardware](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/old-hardware) which I suggest to be tagged into [old-computer](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/old-computer).</strike> - Done!

**EDIT 2:**

<strike>[computer-buying](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/computer-buying) - 4/10 are closed, mainly used for shopping reccommendations</strike> - not to be removed; see [Burn [computer-buying] tag](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3753/burn-computer-buying-tag) (thanks @SimonSheehan)

**EDIT 3:**
Synonyms: [shutdown](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/shutdown) & [system-shutdown](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/system-shutdown)

---

(edit #1 to include my previous suggestions,
[Tag merging suggestion: [joystick] [joypad] [gamepad]](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/4615)
and [Retag suggestion: [old] -> [old-computer] && [old-hardware]](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/4669) )

Comment: All the tags are merged to game-controller. That stuffs done!

Comment: I think with your old hardware stuff, we should bring this back up: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/4669/retag-suggestion-old-old-computer-old-hardware

Comment: See this about computer buying tag http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3753/burn-computer-buying-tag

Comment: [tag:old] & [tag:retro] was killed. [tag:vintage] & [tag:old-computer] was merged into [tag:old-hardware]

Answer (score 3):

Below tags have been removed as of now:

- [draft](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/draft)
- [hidden](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hidden)
- [tooltip](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tooltip)
- [mobile](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mobile)
- [math](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/math)
- [revision](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/revision)
- [recognition](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/recognition)
- [screw](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/screw)
- [scan](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/scan)
- [view](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/view)
- [configurationprogramming](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/configurationprogramming)
- [unixprogramming](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/unixprogramming)
- [quotes](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/quotes)
- [list](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/list) and [lists](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/lists)
- [gaming](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/gaming)
- [purchase](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/purchase)
- [programming](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/programming)
- [differences](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/differences)
- [name](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/name)
- [untagged](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/untagged)

Comment: I think `[scan]` is perfectly fine in the context of images/documents being digitized. Perhaps it should be merged with `[scanner]`.

Comment: the same could be said for virus-scans... I believe that a burnination of [tag:scan]
 is the best route

Comment: Screws‽ `o.O` Are there really that many questions specifically *about screws*? I know there are two or three, but most just happen to have the word screw somewhere in page; certainly not enough to justify a whole tag for it.

Comment: `[mobile]` is now complete.

Comment: `[tooltip]` is now complete.

Comment: `[hidden]` complete now.

Comment: @SimonSheehan you're doing all my work :P

Comment: @KronoS :) haha, it was quick.

Answer (score 3):

These need to be cleaned up too.

Completed:

- <strike>[verizon-wireless](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/verizon-wireless)</strike>
- <strike>[blogger](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/blogger)</strike>
- <strike>[smartphone](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/smartphone)</strike>

Comment: I added the Do Not Use links to these tags.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>[mapping](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mapping)</strike> - which is a synonym of map - its being used for drive mapping as well as memory mapping, and has no wiki entry

EDIT: All usage of tag removed. I have no idea how to cross it out tho

Comment: Burninate this tag!

Comment: I've done this for you, but for future ref, you just use `<strike></strike>` :) Oh and great job!  That was a daunting one.

Comment: Just landed here as I was going to add "mapping" to [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/532071/streets-and-trips-data-import-wizard-use-address-instead-of-long-lat). What should we use for mapping software/sites then? Create separate tags for each program/site, like there exist already for google-maps and bing-maps?

Comment: technically google maps and bing maps belong on webapps.I'd think a specific program name, and/or something like [gis] (which has its own site too) may work better

Answer (score 2):

Tag Synonym Suggestions for this cleanup session:

- [duplicate](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/duplicate) <-> [duplicate-files](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/duplicate-files)

Answer (score 1):

Here are my findings, I hope it helps:

- [usb-flash-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/usb-flash-drive), [usb-storage](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/usb-storage)
- [configuration](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/configuration) , [configure](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/configure)
- [troubleshooting](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/troubleshooting) , [diagnostic](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/diagnostic), [diagnose](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/diagnose)

Comment: I'm assuming you mean duplicates here right?

Comment: Correct assumption

Comment: `configure` could be the `./configure` step in compiling software. I also don't agree that `troubleshooting` fully overlaps with `diagnostic/diagnose`.

Answer (score 1):

I only have one tag clean-up suggestion so far:

- [script](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/script) <-> [scripting](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/scripting)

The system won't let me suggest it myself (says I need 5 rep on the tag).

Comment: this is done, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Regarding [history](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/history), are we replacing it with [browser-history](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/browser-history) and [command-history](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/command-history) where applicable?

Or should we get rid of the two other tags as well?