# alternative vs software-rec tags

Tags: discussion, retag-request

Do we really need [alternative](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/alternative) when we have [software-rec](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/software-rec)?

Not only is [alternative](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/alternative) vague in meaning, but most of the questions that use it are looking for software recommendations.

Also, given [this post](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/4383/why-is-looking-for-alternative-programs-not-constructive), would it be better to burninate the tag or make it a synonym for [software-rec](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/software-rec).

Comment: Since there's about 140 posts with it, I think making it a [tag:software-rec] might be better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, there really is no similarity of the two tags.  The removal of [alternative](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/alternative) is what I suggest.

Comment: The `alternative` tag could make a good indicator for close candidates, for soliciting product recommendations...

Comment: @DanielBeck I suggest we remove this tag similar to what is happening with the [Summer Tag Cleanup](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5054/super-user-mid-2012-tag-question-cleanup)

Comment: Yes, but before that, we could take a look at the tagged topics to see whether they need to be closed.

Answer (score 2):

I've merged [alternative](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/alternative) to [software-rec](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/software-rec), but haven't created a synonym - it don't think the synonym suits it.