# Add tag synonym: "preferences" -> "settings"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, tag-synonym-request

Add [preferences](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/preferences) as a synonym of [settings](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/settings).

Comment: Hm. Do you think these tags are useful at all? I'm inclined to have them removed entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I merged [preferences](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/preferences) into [settings](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/settings). The latter is part of the [Super User mid 2012 tag/question cleanup](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5054/super-user-mid-2012-tag-question-cleanup) anyway. So this is a great chance to get them all cleaned up together.

I did not create a synonym.

Answer (score 6):

I disagree with the synonymization, because I see a distinct difference between a *preference* and a *setting*.

> A *preference* is tied to a personal choice, a *setting* is not

However, I feel like **both** tags serve little purpose and should be removed.

They convey so little information or meaning in our context that I would not even propose a replacement. *Maybe* something in the area of [configuration](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/configuration).

There is also these guys:

- [options](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/options)
- [default-settings](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/default-settings)
- <s>[nvidia-settings](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/nvidia-settings)</s>
- [monitor-settings](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/monitor-settings)

Comment: While I agree with your quoted line, the tag as written, "Preferences", would be my first choice concerning the OSX Preference Panes.  A quick search and cursory browsing of the questions tagged with "Preferences" seems to concur.  It that sense, I could certainly see the similarity with settings, but in this particular regard, I might suggest that closer match would be "control-panel"

Comment: also, the "settings" for mac applications are reached through the "preferences" menu item.

Comment: Isn't nvidia-settings a program?

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail: Great catch! http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/nvidia-settings

Comment: What about the tag word: [options]  ?  aren't these also settings related?

Comment: @Saariko: Yes, another target :) Thanks, I added it to the list for now.