# List of tag merge requests (Dec 2012)

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

Merge:

- <s>merge [php-ini](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/php-ini) x2 => [php.ini](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/php.ini) 10x</s>
- <s>merge [autofill](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/autofill) x1 => [auto-form-fill](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/auto-form-fill) 3x</s>
- <s>merge [dos](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dos) 2x => [ms-dos](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ms-dos) 91x (checked their posts. They mean ms-dos)</s>
- <s>synonym [mainboard](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mainboard) 2x => [motherboard](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/motherboard) 954x</s>

Split:

- <s>split [boot-repair](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/boot-repair) 1x => [boot](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/boot) 2065x + [repair](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/repair) 242x</s>
- <s>split [windows-boot](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-boot) 1x => [boot](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/boot) 2065x + [windows](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows) 15955x</s>

Remove:

- <s>remove [fdl](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/fdl) 1x => has different meanings (abbreviation for at least [16 different names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FDL))</s>
- <s>remove [metax](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/metax) 1x => has different meanings (there are several firms and product names with metax)</s>
- <s>remove [system-settings](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/system-settings) 1x => too general</s>
- <s>remove [identity](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/identity) 1x => too general</s>

---

I just learned that there is an [*periodically cleaned up*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13485/auto-remove-tags-left-without-an-associated-question/13487#13487) of unused tags.

**Some questions**

- I assume the periodically cleaned up is done through a scheduled task.
  If so, what period is used?
- Are unused tags removed when all related questions are migrated to other sites? Like [heimdall](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/heimdall)
- Are unused tags removed when all related questions are closed?
  Like [sql-schema-compare](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sql-schema-compare) [custom-rom](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/custom-rom) [geofences](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/geofences) [xkcd](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/xkcd) [dual-gpu](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dual-gpu) [donate](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/donate)
- Is there a guiding principle for when to merge tags and when to use it as synonym?
- is there an intended place where I should post tag merge & split suggestions?
  Unfortunately  [Super User mid 2012 tag/question cleanup](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5054/super-user-mid-2012-tag-question-cleanup) is closed
- <del>How can I search for tags used **only once** and sort them by time to find very old and unnecessary tags?  That would be great (these [search tips](https://meta.superuser.com/search) don't help)</del>

Comment: Try the following query on [Data.SE](http://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/query/new): `SELECT TOP 100 Posts.Id as [Post Link], Tags.TagName, Posts.LastActivityDate
FROM Posts JOIN PostTags ON Posts.Id = PostTags.PostId JOIN Tags ON Tags.Id = PostTags.TagId WHERE Tags.Count = 1 ORDER BY Posts.LastActivityDate`

Comment: @Daniel Beck: That is very impressive!

Comment: @Moderators, please also synonymize after merging (e.g `[dos]`).

Comment: @tempy: I'm not sure about synonymize this. DOS can stand for [many things](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS).

Comment: Went through with the merges / synonyms. For splitting, we're gonna have to do that manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I assume the periodically cleaned up is done through a scheduled task.
>   If so, what period is used?

From Jeff: *I've implemented a routine that removes tags created more than 6 months ago which have been used only a single time. It will run monthly.*

So, either nuke bad tags once you see them—10k users can do that from [the stats page in the tools](https://superuser.com/tools?tab=stats&daterange=last30days)—or just browse the [tags page](https://superuser.com/tags?page=159&tab=popular) in the reverse order.

> Are unused tags removed when all related questions are migrated to other sites?

Yes, since migration stubs are removed if IIRC.

> Are unused tags removed when all related questions are closed?

No, since closed questions can be reopened. Unless there's only one question tagged with it.

> Is there a guiding principle for when to merge tags and when to use it as synonym?

We usually merge after synonymizing. Actually, the fact that you can have synonyms without a merge stems from the [possibility to suggest synonyms](https://superuser.com/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms), which can be community-approved. However, only moderators can actually perform a merge.

Comment: Since you answered every question except the one regarding an intended place to suggest many retag-requests, I assume there isn't one. So I feel free to post one question per request....or just re-use this question.

Comment: Well, ideally focus on one set of similar tags, one request per time. This makes it easier for us to go through the [`retag-request`] tag and complete them individually.

Comment: There is [Tag cleanup for December 2012](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5718/tag-cleanup-for-december-2012). Seems to be a good place to post tag merge requests, or not?

Comment: Yes, but we're already quite
busy  with those that we have :)

Answer (score 3):

**This second part is based on a Query on data.stackexchange.com**
Query: [Superuser tags only used once - sorted by creation time](http://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/query/90386/first-100-tags-used-only-once-sorted-by-creation-date)

---

All these tags are created prior 01.01.2012 and thus far only the creator uses the tag.
Since they are older than 6 months, I vote for removing them manually.

[harmony](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/harmony) 2009-08-15
[ipx](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ipx) 2009-09-17
[nexus-one](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/nexus-one) 2010-01-19
[browser-helper-objects](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/browser-helper-objects) 2010-05-28
[process-monitor](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/process-monitor) 2010-11-17
[euler](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/euler) 2010-12-19
[apt-on-cd](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/apt-on-cd) 2010-12-24
[vector-linux](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/vector-linux) 2011-03-21
[earth](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/earth) 2011-04-07
[dma](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dma) 2011-10-26
[rbash](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/rbash) 2011-12-03

> From Jeff: *I've implemented a routine that removes tags created more than 6 months ago which have been used only a single time. It will run monthly.*

Hm, I'm curious. Why hasn't this routine caught the tags from above?
Of course it may be that a second question (using this tag) was retagged during the last month and it will get cleaned up on the next run.

Or they are nasty little tags creeping deep inside the database and will someday get admin privileges. :P

Comment: Maybe these tags *have* been used multiple times, but questions tagged with them have been deleted? Could also be a bug, of course.