# Advice on approving edits

Tags: discussion, questions, review

I have noticed a wave of improved tag edits in the review bin. I am seeking advice or awarness on the quality aspect of tag only edits.

Is this something that is OK on a large scale?

Note, I did not look yet to see if any of the old tags were on the "get rid of list" yet, but I will. Just wondering in general.

Comment: What do you mean by tag only edits?  Like just the excerpt? or the wiki or both?

Comment: Or are you talking about adding tags to the question?

Comment: Eliminate two tags, and replace with tow dif. tags as an example.

Comment: So you're talking about edits within the question and not tag wiki's.

Comment: @KronoS - correct. not tag wiki's

Answer (score 3):

If the edit to the question is simply a change in tags it shouldn't be approved except in the following two cases:

### 1. The Question clearly is mis/poorly tagged

This will be more of a rarer case than you think, because if the question is poorly/mis tagged then more than likely the content, and title of the question is of the same low quality.  If the edit only fixes the tags but neglects any other issues with spelling, grammar or formatting, it should be rejected as *too minor*.

### 2. The tag is a part of the tag cleanup movement

This will be more likely of the two scenarios.  You can tell if the tag is decommissioned by hovering over it and looking at the description for the text:

> DO NOT USE - Removed as part of Super User mid 2012 cleanup - [Super User mid 2012 tag/question cleanup](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5054/super-user-mid-2012-tag-question-cleanup)